# Data model strategy (workflow)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an application to help mechanize service request work on my helpdesk and am trying to wrap my head around how to attack the following problem:

1. I create a department
2. In the department, there are different types of work requests
3. For each work request, there may be one or more work plans to satisfy the request
4. Each work plan contains multiple steps (and these steps are done in sequence)

I sorted the underlying models to create and manage the departments, work requests and work plans (without steps or sequence) and am looking for a bit of input as to if I should:

a. Add the steps to the work plan itself
 b. Create a separate step model that contains all steps and then the work plan references the steps and adds sequencing
 c. If there is a better way to do it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for

```
department
  has_many work_requests

work_request
  belongs_to department
  belongs_to work_request_type
  + additional fields like owner, ...

work_request_type
  type : string
  has_many work_requests
  has_and_belongs_to_many work_plans

work_plan
  has_and_belongs_to_many work_request_types
  has_many steps

step
  belongs_to work_plan
  order_of_execution : integer
```

Comment: So in this approach would I build a UI for adding steps in order, and then bind the steps with their order to a work plan and then render the work plan as an option for a work_request_type?  I'm tripping on the linkage from steps to work plans (I get the work plan to step fine - just the database of steps is where I'm tripping)

Comment: Easiest seems to use a nested form to edit the steps in your work plan. Each step has a description and an order. You add a "plus" and a "minus" to add and remove steps. In your show page you show the workplan with the steps sorted by order. In your edit page, you show them in order as well. When you change the order numbers, I would not rearrange them at once. This would require javascript, and doesn't add "much value" to start with.

Comment: Got it.  Final question and then'll I'll mark this closed (and many thanks).  Can you point me to any examples of the UI (nested form)? Haven't done that before and I think I can finish this today with that point.  (Either way I'll mark it answered shortly).  And thanks!

Comment: If this is your first nested form: go for Ryan Bates gem: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form. Works perfect - and simple to integrate!